# fazer um grupo de ID iguais

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Bom, eu tenho uma tabela que retorna 5 usuarios, sendo que entre esses 5 podem haver teamID iguais, exemplo:

```
usuario1 = teamid: 51
usuario2 = teamid: 51
usuario3 = teamid: 55
usuario4 = teamid: 55
usuario5 = teamid: null
```

eu gostaria de saber como eu definiria um grupo para eles por id iguais sendo, se o quem é id 51, pertence ao time 1, id 52 pertence ao time 2, o que tem id NULL não tem time(detalhe pode haver ocasiões que todos sejam do mesmo id).

aqui há um exemplo de como  funciona, existe 2 times, time vencedor tem um grupo completo, time perdedor tem 1 grupo de duas pessoas, porém estou mostrando o ID ao invés de time 1 e 2,3 etc..

https://theevie.club/match/PC/212048062

Answer (score 0):

Você provavemente deverá fazer uma tabela auxiliar contendo o temid e o grupo com seu nome, por exemplo: 55 = grupo 1 e 51 = grupo 2, inclusive podendo colocar mais detalhes sobre este grupo.

Pesquise na internet sobre chave estrangeira em banco de dados que é o que vc precisa. Aí depois vc pode tentar implementar esta on seu sistema